# How to dynamically set HTML tag in an XPage

Tags: xpages

In my standard webpage I have the foloowing code, but how to I do this in an XPage?

```
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get away with putting the classes in the <body> tag, you could do it centrally via a theme so there's no need to repeat the code on every page:

```
    <control>
        <name>ViewRoot</name>
        <property>
            <name>styleClass</name>
            <value>#{javascript:if (context.getUserAgent().isIE(0,6)) {
    return 'no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7';
} else if (context.getUserAgent().isIE(7,7)) {
    return 'no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8';
} else if (context.getUserAgent().isIE(8,8)) {
    return 'no-js lt-ie9';
}}</value>
        </property>
    </control>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by adding attributes to the UIViewRoot component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

   <xp:this.attrs>

      <!-- if browser is IE 7 or smaller -->
      <xp:attr name="class" value="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"
         rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE(0,7)}">
      </xp:attr>

      <!-- if browser is NOT IE 7 or smaller -->
      <xp:attr name="class" value="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"
         rendered="#{javascript:!(context.getUserAgent().isIE(0,7))}">
      </xp:attr>

   </xp:this.attrs>

</xp:view>
```

The *lang* attribute is computed by current language settings of the XPage.
To do this application / server wide you have to add this to a theme.

**EDIT:**

The theme has to look like this:

```
<control>
   <name>ViewRoot</name>
      <property>
         <name>attrs</name>
            <complex type="xp_attr">
               <property>
                  <name>name</name>
                  <value>class</value>
               </property>
               <property>
                  <name>value</name>
                  <value>#{javascript:
                     if (context.getUserAgent().isIE(0,6)) {
                        return 'no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7';
                     }
                     if (context.getUserAgent().isIE(7,7)) {
                        return 'no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8';
                     }
                     if (context.getUserAgent().isIE(8,8)) {
                        return 'no-js lt-ie9';
                     }
                     return '';
                    }</value>
            </property>
         </complex>
      </property>
</control>
```

The empty return is required, otherwise the theme will fail.

Comment: Very smart. I was trying to do this with a theme but could only get the classes into the <body> tag

Comment: Added the theme version to my answer.

Comment: I would prefer single attr with computed value property. In this specific case cascade of ?: operators would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which bowser, via code on this webpage http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Browser_compatibility

The if then else you can use in a computed text, the fast way. And in the if statements return the correct html.
You need to set the computed text to HTML

Comment: The example HTML code is about setting the toplevel <html> tag, I don't think you can do that with computed text.

Comment: thimop, i agreed. I didn't read very well. It is a level higher then a  normal tag.